# Is it possible to use react native and springboot,if so how can i configure a database connection

Tags: java, android, react-native, spring-data-jpa

How can I use springboot dependencies like JPA and Hibernate and databases like mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the RestAPI is totally independant from your frontend client... you will use Spring Boot to send and recieve JSON data from/to the React Native client (frontend).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).